# validate html 5 pattern tel

Tags: html, input, pattern-matching

hi there I try to validate a phone number like this

```
080********
081********
082********
083********
```

I try these:

```
<input type="tel" name="signupMobileTel" placeholder="08121234567" size=11 
pattern="/^(08([0-3]{1}[0-9]{1})([0-9]{7}))*$/" 
aria-describedby="signupMobileTel" required pattern="tel">
```

but I got error.

Comment: What error you are getting.

Comment: you are defining the pattern attribute two times

Comment: when I submit form, for example it can not validate 08123456789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the pattern attribute does not need the start and end slashes so

```
pattern="^(08([0-3]{1}[0-9]{1})([0-9]{7}))*$"
```

works.

You also have the pattern attribute defined twice

Answer (score 1):

How about this? `/(0)\d{11}/`

It starts by either looking for 0, and then followed by 11 digits.

or this

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[0][0-9]{11}">
```

get more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)